# Passing data should be visible in another page, But I am getting inside table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The `Comment` Component is returning data to a table. I want to add a functionality here is Click on `description`(row should work as link), it redirects to another page and will display only description details.
*Table has only 3 columns `description`, `severity`, `status`.*

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import IssuesDetails from "./issuesDetails";

export default class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      href1: "",
      showingDetails: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({pass:this.props.description});
    
  }
  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.showingDetails) {
      // *** Already showing details, just turn the flag off
      this.setState({ showingDetails: false });
  }else{
    const result = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to view the details?");
    if (result) {
      // *** Set the flag
      this.setState({ showingDetails: true });
      
      
  }
  }
  }
    
  render() {
    const { showingDetails } = this.state;
    const href = showingDetails ? "/issues/details" : "/issues";
    
    return (
      <>
        {/* href={`/issues/details`} */}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href={href} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              {this.props.description}
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>{this.props.severity}</td>
          <td>{this.props.children}</td>
        </tr>
        {showingDetails ? <IssuesDetails pass={this.props.description} /> : null}
      </>
      
    );
    
  }
}
```